# Not able to load data URL for GCM push notification for chrome in 'notificationclick' event

Tags: javascript, service-worker, chrome-gcm, web-push, push-api

While working on GCM push notification for Chrome, I have set up push notifications for when a service worker receives a push event for GCM.

I am launching a service call. That service returns a data object in which I have a URL which I want to open at the time when the user clicks on the notification

Here is the code I have so far.

```
Var urlOpen = null;
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        fetch(serviceLink).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status !== 200) {
                console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                response.status);
                throw new Error();
            }
            return response.json().then(function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var title = data.title;
                var body = data.desc;
                var icon = data.image;
                var tag = 'notification tag';
                urlOpen = data.clickUrl;


              return  self.registration.showNotification(title, {
                    body: body,
                    icon: icon,
                    tag: tag
                })
            });
        })
    );
});


self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
        event.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow(urlOpen).then(function (){
         event.notification.close();}));

});
```

This is working fine but sometime on some device notifications. But when  clicking on notifications, it's opening `null` in the browser url bar.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't count on your service worker existing between the `push` event and the `notificationclick` event. The browser may very well shut down the worker after the `push` event has been handled, and then restart it for the `notificationclick` event, meaning that your `urlOpen` variable has been reinitialized to `null`.

I think you can probably store the url on the notification object itself somehow, which would be nicest - looks like there is [an example of that here](https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo/blob/master/src/service-worker.js). Otherwise you would have to save it to indexedDB or something like that.

Comment: Thanks Brendan!! I have stored url in notification.data and it working fine now

Comment: Hello, 
Example URL is not working. However I have tried your suggestion. I will share results.

Comment: looks like it is here now: https://github.com/gauntface/simple-push-demo/blob/master/src/service-worker.js